# Calling Ant via Bash Script from Other Program (Mac OSX)

Tags: bash, macos, ant, android-ndk

I have a bash script that calls "ant -v debug". I can all this from a Terminal command line prompt without any problems.

I am trying to get this script to run via an IDE (CodeLite) but I appear to be missing some environment variable or other setup when running it this way.

Ant responds with:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher
```

My script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
export ANDROID_SDK=/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_NDK=/Android/android-ndk-r9d
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK/tools:$ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools:$ANDROID_NDK:/work/bin
export ANT_HOME=/opt/ant

cd /work/TT/android-TT
ant -v debug
echo
echo Complete
```

I have ran 'env' at the command prompt and I cannot see any Java or 'classpath' environment variables at all, so I don't have any idea what is missing. The script must be missing some class path environment variable surely?

What is missing? How can I configure the script's environment so that ANT will run successfully?

UPDATE: Here is the output from including `--execdebug`

```
exec "$JAVACMD" -classpath "$LOCALCLASSPATH" -Dant.home="$ANT_HOME" -Dant.library.dir="$ANT_LIB" org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher -cp "$CLASSPATH" "-v" "debug"
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher
```

Also, if I run from CodeLite *or* the command line, the below environment variables are all blank (except ANT_HOME that I set in my script) ????

```
CLASSPATH=
LOCALCLASSPATH=
ANT_LIB=
ANT_HOME=/opt/ant
```

How can java possibly find any classes if the `CLASSPATH` is blank?

Comment: What is the output of running: `ant -v debug --execdebug`

Comment: What if you ran ANT with the full path? just to try... i've a feeling about this :)

Comment: @ivoruJavaBoy Same result I'm afraid.

Comment: @ChadNouis I have added the --execdebug output to the question.

Comment: @ivoruJavaBoy 'ant' appears to be nothing more than a shell script itself.. ???

Comment: It seems to be a configuration issue, but the fact strange is that is working as usual when you call it from command line...

Comment: @ivoruJavaBoy Hmm. I switched IDE from CodeLite to KomodoIDE and its working fine. Totally environmental.

Comment: It is surprising that `--execdebug` is showing unevaluated variables such as `$JAVACMD`. What version of Ant is this? What is the output of `ant -version`? Is the output of `ant -version` different if you run the command from the script versus directly running the command?

Comment: @ChadNouis Version reports "Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.7 compiled on April 9 2016" when run from Terminal..

Comment: @ChadNouis I can't even get ant -version to work from CodeLite - I get the same cannot find or load main class error. I even tried adding the full path to it...

Comment: @ChadNouis Now it gets interesting! If I run ant at the full path where I installed it, I get the class error.. so I must have more than one version of ANT installed. Somebody did say that ANT is installed as part of Xcode so that could be the case. Now I need to find out the path of the version of ANT that is being called when I just type 'ant' at the command line..

Comment: @ChadNouis Thanks to the 'which' command, I found that the correct path of ant is '/usr/local/bin/ant'. I now call ant using that path from within my script that's called from CodeLite and it works! If you write up an official answer to this question, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the 'which' command, I found that the correct path of ant is '/usr/local/bin/ant'. I now call ant using that path from within my script that's called from CodeLite and it works!